# passing values from .blade to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

i have a page that shows many products and each one has a link to view its details,
this is the code that leads to the link:

```
 <a class="btn-danger" href="{{ url('viewpartydetails/'.$party->party_id) }}">
                    view details
                </a>
```

and this is the route : `Route::get('viewpartydetails/{party_id}','PartyController@partydetails');`

and this is the code in the controller:

```
public function partydetails($party_id)
    {
        if(!Auth::guest())
        { // $party_id=request('partyid');
            $party = DB::table('party1')->where('party_id',$party_id)->get();
           //dd($party_id);
            return view('partydetails',compact('party'));
        }
        else
            return redirect()->guest('login');

    }
```

the problem is the page that i want to show is appearing without any design!!!
but when i delete this part "/{party_id}" all designs are showing up again !!!
what is the problem? 
this is the view page :

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div id="fh5co-main">
        <div class="fh5co-narrow-content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    <h2 class="fh5co-heading animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft">About Us Nitro <span>A Web Studio</span></h2>
                    <p class="fh5co-lead animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft">Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean.</p>
                    <p class="animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft"> Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-1 animate-box" data-animate-effect="fadeInLeft">
                    <img src="images/img_1.jpg" alt="Free HTML5 Bootstrap Template" class="img-responsive">
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

app.blade code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- #Dışarıdan Çağırılan Dosyalar Font we Materyal İkonlar Bitiş -->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,600,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <!-- Animate.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    <!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <!-- Owl Carousel -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

    <!-- Modernizr JS -->
    <script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body background="images/party1.jpeg">

    <div id="app">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">

                    <!-- Collapsed Hamburger -->
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#app-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>

                    <!-- Branding Image -->
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                        {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                    </a>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="app-navbar-collapse">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        &nbsp;
                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @if (Auth::guest())
                            <li><a href="{{ route('login') }}">Login</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ route('register') }}">Register</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                            onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                            Logout
                                        </a>

                                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                            {{ csrf_field() }}
                                        </form>
                                    </li>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ url('viewparties') }}">
                                            view parties
                                        </a>

                                    </li>
                                    @if(Auth::user()->user_type=="organizer")
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="{{ url('add_party') }}">
                                            add a party
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                    @endif
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        @endif
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        @yield('content')

    </div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Easing -->
    <script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->

    <!-- Carousel -->
    <script src="js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Stellar -->
    <script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Waypoints -->
    <script src="js/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Counters -->
    <script src="js/jquery.countTo.js"></script>


    <!-- MAIN JS -->
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you show your view ?

Comment: @BenjaminBrasseur done

Comment: I think that the issue is coming from your `layouts/app.blade.php`. Can you show it too please ?

Comment: Your main css is `css/style1.css` ?

Comment: style1.css is coming with the free template which i downloaded 
style.css is from laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is coming from your differents css links tags.

Actually you have :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,600,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<!-- Animate.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
<!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
<!-- Bootstrap  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<!-- Owl Carousel -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<!-- Theme style  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<!-- Modernizr JS -->
<script src="js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
```

Then when you're using the `/{party_id}` route, your browser try to find 
`localhost/{party_id}/css/style.css` instead of `localhost/css/style.css`

The solution is to use `asset()` like you can see at the top of your **layout view**  `<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">`

So it should be something like that :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('css/style1.css') }}">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}">

<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,600,400italic,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


<!-- Animate.css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/animate.css') }}">
<!-- Icomoon Icon Fonts-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/icomoon.css') }}">
<!-- Bootstrap  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.css') }}">
<!-- Owl Carousel -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/owl.carousel.min.css') }}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/owl.theme.default.min.css') }}">
<!-- Theme style  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/style.css') }}">

<!-- Modernizr JS -->
<script src="{{ asset('js/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js') }}"></script>
```